# keep all column after sum and groupby including empty values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
source  name    cost  other_c  other_b
a       a       7     dd        33
b       a       6     gg        44
c       c       3     ee        55
b       a       2               
d       b       21    qw        21
e       a       16    aq 
c       c       10              55
```

I am doing a sum of name and source with:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['source', 'name'], as_index=False)['cost'].sum()
```

but it is dropping the remaining 6 columns in my dataframe. Is there a way to keep the rest of the columns? I'm not looking to add new column, just carry over the columns from the original dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy his  example you provided is to create a new column, while the task at hand is to merely keep the column from my previous dateframe where the groupby occured

Comment: my bad. Have a look at the suggested solutions

Comment: @Aldo - How looks expected output after sum ?

Comment: after review the outcome this is actually getting the data I am looking for